# Linux process is sending some junk characters to the STDOUT. No Controlling terminal attached to it

Tags: linux, kubernetes, container

I have a containerized unimrcp server and it is running as kubernetes pod. When I go inside container and do `ps -ef` its output is like this:

```
[root@unimrcp-0 fd]# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0 99 13:13 ?        01:07:38 ./unimrcpserver
root        75     1  0 13:13 ?        00:00:00 [arping] <defunct>
root        76     1  0 13:13 ?        00:00:00 [arping] <defunct>
root       154     0  0 13:14 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
root       209   154  0 14:21 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Also if I do `cat /proc/[pid]/fd/1` then I am seeing some corrupted output like this:

unknown command: ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

Why there is no controlling terminal attached with the process. I have disabled the Unimrcp from logging to stdout. Also the CPU utilization is 99%. Can someone please help to solve this?

This is the entrypoint of the container

```
#!/bin/sh
source /ip-conf.sh; set_control_media_network "UNIMRCP"
CONTROL_IP=$(get_control_ipv4)
MEDIA_IP=$(get_media_ipv4)
LOG_LEVEL=$(echo $LOG_LEVEL | tr -s " " | xargs)
LOG_OUTPUT=$(echo $LOG_OUTPUT | tr -s " " | xargs)
LOG_HEADERS=$(echo $LOG_HEADERS | tr -s " " | xargs)
sed -i 's+<priority>.*</priority>+''<priority>'$LOG_LEVEL'</priority>+g' 
/usr/local/unimrcp/conf/logger.xml
sed -i 's+<output>.*</output>+''<output>'$LOG_OUTPUT'</output>+g' 
/usr/local/unimrcp/conf/logger.xml
sed -i 's+<headers>.*</headers>+''<headers>'$LOG_HEADERS'</headers>+g' 
/usr/local/unimrcp/conf/logger.xml
sed -i 's+<!-- <ip>.*</ip> -->+''<ip>'$CONTROL_IP'</ip>+g' 
/usr/local/unimrcp/conf/unimrcpserver.xml
sed -i 's+<!-- <rtp-ip>.*</rtp-ip> -->+''<rtp-ip>'$MEDIA_IP'</rtp-ip>+g' 
/usr/local/unimrcp/conf/unimrcpserver.xml 
cd /usr/local/unimrcp/bin/
exec ./unimrcpserver
```

This is the output of the ls -l at the /proc/1/fd/ inside the unimrcp container

```
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 1 -> pipe:[17601930]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 10 -> pipe:[17605635]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 11 -> socket:[17605636]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 12 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 13 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 14 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 15 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 16 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 17 -> socket:[17602110]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 18 -> socket:[17602111]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 19 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 2 -> pipe:[17601931]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 20 -> socket:[17603083]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 21 -> socket:[17603084]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 22 -> /dev/urandom
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 23 -> socket:[17603087]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 24 -> socket:[17603088]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 3 -> 
/usr/local/unimrcp/log/unimrcpserver_2020.01.02_12.04.08.988860.log
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 4 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 5 -> pipe:[17605633]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 6 -> pipe:[17605633]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 7 -> socket:[17605634]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 8 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 9 -> pipe:[17605635]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was because of process not having TTY attached to it. TTY is the device used by the process to interact for the purpose of input and output. Since there was no TTY, Unimrcp process used its fd 1 (stdout) for its one of the thread communications (fd 1 was attached the process's pipe). Hence there were some junk characters sent to stdout (do not know exactly why?).

After attaching the tty to the process, process fd 1 pointed to /dev/pts/0 which is the pseudo terminal. Now I am able to see the logs in readble format.

Added these lines to pod yaml file. which solved the issue

`containers:
    - name: unimrcp
      tty: true
      stdin: true`

Answer (score 1):

You need to double quote your variable expansions.

In the command

```sh
sed -i 's+<headers>.*</headers>+''<headers>'$LOG_HEADERS'</headers>+g' /usr/local/unimrcp/conf/logger.xml
```

the variable expansion `$LOG_HEADERS` is unquoted.  This means that if the variable `LOG_HEADERS` contains spaces, it will be split into multiple words (and each word will additionally undergo filename globbing).

This means that if `$LOG_HEADERS` is the string `A B C`, you will get the command

```sh
sed -i 's+<headers>.*</headers>+''<headers>'A B C'</headers>+g' /usr/local/unimrcp/conf/logger.xml
```

In this command, `B`, `C</headers>+g` and `/usr/local/unimrcp/conf/logger.xml` will be taken as pathnames of files to process, and the `sed` expression `s+<headers>.*</headers>+<headers>A` to apply to those files contains a syntax error.

Always double quote any variable expansions.  There are instances where double quoting an expansion is not needed, but it's much easier to remember to always use double quotes.

Your command would look like either

```sh
sed -i 's+<headers>.*</headers>+''<headers>'"$LOG_HEADERS"'</headers>+g' /usr/local/unimrcp/conf/logger.xml
```

or

```sh
sed -i "s+<headers>.*</headers>+<headers>$LOG_HEADERS</headers>+g" /usr/local/unimrcp/conf/logger.xml
```

(in fact, there would be only a single `sed` command as you can easily string together several edits in one invocation by either separating each expression with `;`, or giving them in separate `-e 'expression'` arguments).

You also need to double quote the expansions when you're using them with `echo`.

Also note that parsing XML is *much* easier and more robust with an XML parser.  To replace the contents of a `<header>` tag, you might, for example, use

```
$ cat file.xml
<root>
<header>hello</header>
</root>
```

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//header' -v "new data" file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <header>new data</header>
</root>
```

Questions and answers relating to quoting:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Apart from that, your script lacks the initial `#`-character on the very first line, and you seem to ignore whether your `cd` successfully changes the working directory or not (do you really want to set the working directory to `/usr/local/unimrcp/bin` by the way?).

Comment: I have the # in my script. but it got missed while copying here. cd is changing the directory to /usr/local/unimrcp/bin .

Comment: I tried above suggestion still it is giving me the same error

Comment: @user3553913 Sorry, what error? Your question does not mention an error at all.

Comment: I am still getting those Junk characters sent to the stdout. Infact in the configuration file logger.xml I have prevented the application from printing it to the stdout. I have configured only to log to a file. But still this unimrcp process is writing these junk chars to stdout

Comment: @user3553913 I'm assuming that you still have some quoting issues in your script then. You may want to resort to more traditional debugging techniques, like making sure that each individual edit with `sed` to your configuration file looks OK.

Comment: Thanks, but the configurations that I am setting through the script are inserted properly into the logger.xml. The problem is with the process's stdout is bound to wrong pipe. This is the output of the ls -l

Comment: total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 1 -> pipe:[17601930]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 10 -> pipe:[17605635]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 11 -> socket:[17605636]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 12 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 13 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 14 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  2 12:04 15 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]

Comment: @user3553913 Well, you don't redirect the output of the process in the code that you show us, so the issue lies elsewhere. Either in the program itself, or in whatever is calling the script.

Comment: script is called like this ENTRYPOINT . ./unimrcp_entrypoint.sh This is the docker entrypoint. The issue is because the process is not attached to any terminal. ps -ef shows TTY as ?. This Unimrcp is the first process that will be spawned by the OS.